# Getting information from database don't work property

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to get information from database and it's works for simple names but don't work for more complicated. Example working for `/?item=Chroma%20Case` but not working for `/?item=★%20Bayonet%20|%20Blue%20Steel%20(Battle-Scarred)` echo show nothing

```
<?php
$item = $_GET['item'];
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);


$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'csgo');


$sql = "SELECT cost FROM `items` WHERE `name` = '$item'";

if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['cost'];
}


?>
```

Comment: You need to parameterize these queries before little bobby tables comes for a visit. http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: Why are you parsing the url that way? You should be using http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `str_replace` change your $_GET value, so you should remove these lines:

```
$item = str_replace("\"", "", $item);
$item = str_replace("\'", "", $item);
$item = str_replace(" ", "%20", $item);
$item = str_replace("\\", "", $item);
```

And you can use `urlencode()` to receive your url paramter with special characters, so your code should be:

```
<?php
$item = urlencode($_GET['item']);

$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'csgo');
$sql = "SELECT cost FROM `items` WHERE `name` = '$item'";
if(!$result = $db->query($sql)){
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
}
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['cost'];
}
?>
```